# Play facebook videos in ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios9

I want to embed Facebook videos in my app. I am getting video links from a webservice. 
For example:

```
"video_url": "https://www.facebook.com/urdutimes.ca/videos/520665921438799/"
```

Is it possible to embed this video in native iOS app using Objective-C?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: You can use  `MPMoviePlayerController`

Comment: Can you please tell me how as I have read somewhere else that MPMoviePlayerController required direct link to the video like http://www.example.com/test.mp4

Comment: Is there any example @Hima

Answer (score -1):

Try this one:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.facebook.com/urdutimes.ca/videos/520665921438799/"];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
mp.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:mp];
```