# Play Face book video in iOS App with Video URL

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have to play Facebook Video in the native iOS App and I am getting the URL from the backend.Any Idea how to implement this?.I have searched in the net but i could not find the answer,I have already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863694/play-facebook-videos-in-ios-application) and it is not working. The url I am getting from back end is in this format : https://www.facebook.com/UdayEdits/videos/1494858037252595/

Comment: Have you tried with AVPlayer?

Comment: Yes but it's not working.

Comment: Try it on WKWebview or UIWebview once. If it plays you can use them instead of native player. For native player to work, you maye have to use Facebook API to procure video url. It may not be possible to play the fb video directly.

Comment: is there any way found to play facebook video url in swift/objective c please share the code here.